# Pass date argument to .exe

Tags: vbscript

Using a .vbs script, I would like to run a .exe with a date argument. The date argument is "next days date". I tried this script below, but I get the error: invalid month in date.

why?

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

NextDayDate = DateAdd("d",1,dtmStart)
WshShell.Run """C:\stmt.exe"" DATE=NextDayDate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBScript doesn't do variable interpolation. You need to simply concatenate the date to the end of the string

```vb
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

NextDayDate = DateAdd("d",1,dtmStart)
WshShell.Run """C:\stmt.exe"" DATE=" & NextDayDate
```

You may need to include quotes if the date has spaces in it (although that may depend on your executable).

```
WshShell.Run """C:\stmt.exe"" DATE=""" & NextDayDate & """"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got an error with DATE=" & NextDayDate. However, after I took out the quote it worked.

Comment: +1, especially because *both* string expessions are correct wrt quotes and operators.

Comment: Although the quotes around the executable path are rather futile as it obviously doesn't contain any spaces. ;) Personally I prefer using a quoting function over escaping double quotes (`Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function`). I believe `"... DATE=" & qq(NextDayDate)` is a lot more readable than `"... DATE=""" & NextDayDate & """"`.