# Cannot startup a program with fixed arguments via vbs

Tags: vbscript, startup

In W10, I want to auto start an app requiring higher privilege within a standard account. This app is quite old and I can easily stat it with but I cannot access the app and cannot see the icon in systray.

I've found a way to do it with a vbs script in the startup folder and it perfectly works but I cannot find a way to add fixed arguments, that I need.  Here's what I need to start :

```
C:\Program files (x86)\K10STAT154\K10STAT.exe -StayOnTray -nw -ClkCtrl:1 -lp:1
```

This is perfectly the VBS script perfectly working :

```
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
 WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\K10STAT154\K10STAT.exe """ ,0  'Must quote command if it has spaces; must escape quotes  Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I just need to add the the 4 arguments.  These arguments are fixed, they never change.

I know nothing about vbs, so it's not easy to try few things but I tried adding the arguments right after .exe with quotes, without quotes, etc.. I get type mismatch errors, expected end of statement, etc ..

An idiot proof answer, would be appreciated !

Thank you so much J Guy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass date argument to .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071219/pass-date-argument-to-exe)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found with many trials and errors .... Here's the working script with arguments, that may serve other people like me :

```
 Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell" ) 
  WshShell.Run """C:\Program Files (x86)\K10STAT154\K10STAT.exe ""-StayOnTray -ClkCtrl:1 -nw -lp:1""""", 0 
  'Must quote command if it has spaces; must escape quotes
  Set WshShell = Nothing
```

I don't understand the double quotes system but ... it works !

J guy